# Grafana _field display name pattern - range or regex maybe

Tags: grafana

I'm wondering if it is possible to set a range in the display name option.

[Display name option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oLSu.png)

I know I can use:

```
${__field.displayName.0}
```

to get the first character from the string used by grafana as a display name for my metric. It would be nice to use something like:

```
${__field.displayName.0:10}
```

Maybe there is an option to use a regex here, this would be nice

I'm using grafphite and the metrics are labeled like:

```
somehost.com.metrics.metrics_name1
somehost.com.metrics.metrics_name2
somehost.com.metrics.metrics_name3
```

and I would like to cut the *somehost.com.metrics.* part from it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Graphite plugin supports aliases with many available functions:

[image: This can be achieved with this setting in Graphite query editor]